# How to use Serilog with Newtonsoft.Json for .Net?

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, serilog

I used Serilog with Elasticsearch in my project. But I need to serialize object fields names from JsonProperty. How I can do this? I think, I need to setup Serilog with Newtonsoft.Json, but I can't find any info about this. Please, help me)

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: I think there is a destructurama.json package or something similar which plugs in to do json.net stuff - not sure if you need to map toa JObject first though

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for this, there is a library https://github.com/destructurama/json-net

You can destructure `JObject` by passing it with a `@`.
For example: `_logger.LogInformation("ProjectVariables: {@Variables}", projectVariables);` where `projectVariables` is a `JObject`