# Serilog cannot destructure anonymous complex objects within a collection

Tags: json, logging, collections, json.net, serilog

I cannot find a way to destructure any collection property that is defined as an anonymous type, and also a complex object, in the Serilog logging framework.

For example:

**Class Definition:**

```
 public class LogRequest
 {
     public string? LogMessage { get; set; }

     public Dictionary<string, object>? AdditionalMetaData { get; set; }
 }
```

**Logging Method in .NET Web API Controller:**

```
[HttpPost("information")]
public void LogInformation([FromBody] LogRequest requestData)
{
    logger.Information("{@requestData}", requestData);
}
```

**JSON Payload of Request**

```
{
    "logMessage": "Test log message",
    "additionalMetaData" :{
        "SomeMetaData": 1234,
        "TimeOfLog": "00:00",
        "SomeOtherObject": {
            "SomeProperty": "Some Value",
            "SomeOtherMetaData": 1234
        }
    }
}
```

**Serilog's interpretation of this object:**

```
{
  requestData: {
    AdditionalMetaData: {
      SomeMetaData: 1234,
      SomeOtherObject: [ 
        [[]],
        [[]]
      ],
      TimeOfLog: 00:00
    },
    LogMessage: Test log message
  }
}
```

As you can see, any complex object that is defined by the incoming payload, within the collection, expressed as an anonymous type, cannot be properly destructured by Serilog. The "SomeOtherObject"'s property values were completely wiped out by Serilog in the interpretation.

I will mention that in this example, I am Deserializing the incoming JSON payload using Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package. The "SomeOtherObject" is being deserialized into a JObject type.

The System.Text.JSon deserialization has the same effect. Serilog interprets the object a little bit differently, but it is still unable to destructure complex objects within an anonymous type, defined as a property in a collection.

Comment: Do these answer your question?  [How to use Serilog with Newtonsoft.Json for .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53168048) and [Serilog loses List<object> property values when serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74030184).

Answer (score 1):

A reference and configuration to Destructurama.JsonNet package did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).